# JAVA RMI Can i register multiple remote objects into one registry with different name?

Tags: java, rmi

On server side, `Route` is the remote interface and i am binding 3 remote objects into one registry.

Would this be possible to use?

```
 try {

        Route c = new Journey("Cork", "Dublin", "2:44");
        Route g = new Journey("Galway", "Dublin", "2:44");
        Route b = new Journey("Bray", "Dublin", "0:44");

        Route stub1 = (Route) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(c,0);
        Route stub2 = (Route) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(g,0);
        Route stub3 = (Route) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(b,0);
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1109);
        registry.bind("Cork", stub1);
        registry.bind("Galway", stub2);
        registry.bind("Bray", stub3);

        System.out.println("Routes are registered.");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Allow the client to book a journey. You should not be able to double book a reservation. This application should have a minimum of 3 journeys to choose from. Each journey should be allowed to have 3 bookings

Comment: Please check the [FAQ - How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask good questions, so that you get good answers. 
Essentially, there is missing a description of your actual problem

Comment: This question makes no sense

Comment: Could you take a look again? please?  Nanne   Leri

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> JAVA RMI Can i register multiple remote objects into one registry with different name?

Yes.

However you can see that instead of waiting 18 hours and having to put up with a lot of uninformed comments, it would have been considerably more efficient just to *try* it.